# SQL Insert with parameters works fine for MSAccess but not on SQL Server

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net, ms-access

I am noticing that the following insertion of binary data works fine when connecting to MSAccess 2010, however when connecting to SQL Server Express 2012, I get an error. Here is the code:

```
Public Shared Sub InsertBlobs(ByRef hash As Hashtable)
    Dim constring As String
    Select Case CONNECTION_TYPE
        Case DBConnection.MS_Access07
            constring = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                        "User ID=Admin;" & _
                        "Data Source=" & ACCESS07_CONNECTION_STRING & ";" & _
                        "Mode=Read|Write;Extended Properties="""";Jet OLEDB:System Database="""";" & _
                        "Jet OLEDB:Registry Path="""";Jet OLEDB:Engine Type=5;Jet OLEDB:Database Locking Mode=0;" & _
                        "Jet OLEDB:Global Partial Bulk Ops=2;Jet OLEDB:Global Bulk Transactions=1;" & _
                        "Jet OLEDB:New Database Password="""";Jet OLEDB:Create System Database=False;" & _
                        "Jet OLEDB:Encrypt Database=False;Jet OLEDB:Don't Copy Locale on Compact=False;" & _
                        "Jet OLEDB:Compact Without Replica Repair=False;Jet OLEDB:SFP=False"
        Case DBConnection.MS_SQL
            constring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & getSQLConnectionString()
    End Select
    Try
        Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(constring)
            myconnection.Open()
            Dim sqlQry As String = "INSERT INTO [UAV_Archive] ([mission_id], [vehicle_plan_gzip], [msn_header]) VALUES " & _
                "(@mission_id, @vehicle_plan_gzip, @msn_header)"
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sqlQry, myconnection)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mission_id", CInt(hash.Item("mission_id")))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vehicle_plan_gzip", CType(hash.Item("vehicle_plan_gzip"), Byte()))
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msn_header", CType(hash.Item("msn_header"), Byte()))
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim debugBreakHere As Integer = 0
    End Try

End Sub
```

And the error I am getting when I am in SQL Server mode is:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@mission_id"

Since the code works when I am connecting to an MSAccess database, I am really not sure how to address this for SQL Server. I know I can connect to the SQL Server because other queries (select queries) work. I know insert works under my account, as I am able to do String based inserts. But I am faltering here.

If it is a datatype issue, why would the error be related to an Integer field?

Comment: As the error message suggests, a local variable is being used within a script that is not declared using the DECLARE statement.

Comment: It's not a datatype issue, it's just that you're trying to pass something as a parameter when it's not actually a parameter (as far as SQL Server is concerned). Parameters aren't used for regular SELECT/INSERT/etc statements, they're used for procedures. You'd need to actually declare the variables in a regular statement (as opposed to having a procedure with default data types).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`System.Data.OleDb` does not actually support named parameters. Parameters are *positional* and must be declared in the same order that their placeholders appear in the command text.

Now, the Access OLEDB provider will *tolerate* named parameters. It will *ignore* the names and just go by their order, but it doesn't have a problem with parameters (and placeholders) having names.

The OLEDB providers for SQL Server are more fussy and will reject named parameters as you have used them. So, for SQL Server ...

This will fail with the error message you describe:

```vb
Dim connStr As String
connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDb;Trusted_Connection=yes"
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
    conn.Open()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "INSERT INTO Clients (LastName, FirstName) VALUES (@LastName, @FirstName)"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", "Thompson")
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", "Gord")
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

However, this will work:

```vb
Dim connStr As String
connStr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDb;Trusted_Connection=yes"
Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr)
    conn.Open()
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "INSERT INTO Clients (LastName, FirstName) VALUES (?, ?)"
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "Thompson")  ' LastName
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", "Gord")  ' FirstName
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```